# Moving from procedural MySQLi interface to object-based

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is this the right way of connecting to the database?

```
<?php

class Connect {

private $servername;
private $serveruser;
private $password;
private $database;

    function __construct($servername, $serveruser, $password, $database )
    {
        $this->servername = $servername;
        $this->serveruser = $serveruser;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    function conn()
    {

        try {
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $serveruser, $password, $database);
        echo "conn success";
        } 
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();    
        }
    }

}
?>
```

And if I would need to access $conn in other .php files, how I would do that?Example from procedural method: `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);` How this string should look like if we use OOP method?

P.S. Please don't tell me anything about PDO.

Comment: Make `$conn` a non-public attribute of the class, instead of being local to just the `conn()` method. Then other methods in the class can refer to `$this->conn` after you've connected.

Comment: You can cause MySQLi to throw exception on error: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php  .. and no, it is not the right way. You keep on trying to make a wrapper for a class, that already is perfectly serviceable. And you should use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) sinstead of that stupid ancient "real escape" function.

Comment: Also, [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), please. The code examples show how to use object oriented interface for calling the escape function, event if you still insist on using the insecure option instead leaning to use prepared statements./

Comment: @tereško ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should actually look like.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli("host","username","password","database");
```

Answer (score -2):

Going with your existing code, I think this might be the only way to maintain your connection instance. i mean if you dont want to do `(new Connect(...))->conn()` each time.

```
<?php

class Connect
{
    private $servername;
    private $serveruser;
    private $password;
    private $database;

    private static $conn = null;

    function __construct($servername, $serveruser, $password, $database )
    {
        $this->servername = $servername;
        $this->serveruser = $serveruser;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    function conn()
    {

        try {
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $serveruser, $password, $database);
        self::$conn = $conn;

        echo "conn success";
        } 
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();    
        }
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (! self::$conn)
        {
            # Initialize
            # (new static(...))->conn();
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }

}

# In your other *.php files
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string(Connect::instance(),$_POST['username']);
```